# Tengo problemas con ajax en React Js

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, formularios

quiero enviar unos datos a mi archivo data.php a traves de AJAX usando la librería Axios(la cual tengo instalada via npm), el problema es que al momento de enviar me saltan advertencias que no entiendo ya que figura como un problema del backend de react, aquí el ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de ver el primer error(que ese está escrito en mi archivo) "onSubmit" me marca lo siguiente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como si hubiera un problema con Axios.
El resto de los erroes son de react cuando ejecuté el comando `npm run build`, esos errores están en build>static>js>3.aba2d42c.chunk.js ; build>statit>js>main.4bd4fca1.chunk.js ; build>static>js>runtime-main.d1305a25.js

Y esos archivos los forma la computadora.

Aquí la evidencia de que está bien instalado axios:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí el codigo de ajax:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En fin, me gustaría saber como arreglar esto para que envie los datos a traves de axios sin problemas ya que es de suma urgencia.

Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Por favor, no subas código en imágenes, porque eso nos dificulta el poder probar tu código y replicar el error.

Comment: Creo que estas enfocando de forma errónea la manera en que se referencia a una url. [Esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64483557/how-do-i-call-a-php-file-with-axios) te ayudará con tu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Usa el otro formato de axios.

```
import axios from 'axios';

...

//URL es una URL válida a un endpoint del server. Ej http://localhost:8080/api/user
//DATA es un objeto Ej: const DATA = { fullName: "", email: "" }

axios.post(URL, DATA)
  .then(response => alert("SEND!"))
  .catch(error => alert(error));
```

Comment: No me funcionó, me sigue pasando los mismos errores. Algun otra sugerencia?

Comment: Primero prueba que tu URL sea válida, con Postman. Una cosa que me di cuenta es que dentronde tu función onSubmit, el parámetro que recibe ya es un objeto con los datos del formulario, así que basta con `data: initialValues` aunque yo lo llamaría values dado que repites cómo llamas a la variable que contiene los parámetros. Quedando `onSubmit: values => { ... }` y `data: values`. La url que pruebes en postman deberá ser la misma que uses en tu código, si no te funciona en postman, menos en tu código, asi que ojo ahí.

Comment: Te hago una consulta de inexperto, al momento de estar construyendo en react no puedo poner en la carpeta components un archivo .php no? Tipo tendría que incluirlo en el hosting pero despues de subir la version  `npm run build`, me explico? Porque yo quiero que todos esos datos vayan al archivo del backend para ser procesados

Comment: Son 2 cosas diferentes. No puedes combinar archivos php con los de react, dado que son front y backend por separado. Piensa que react hace un build de tu proyecto el cual deberá recién ahí desplegarse donde lo necesites. Idealmente tu backend debe estar configurado como una api (recibiendo las llamadas de cada endpoint) entregandole las respuestas al frontend.